# Hide woocommerce-message in couple seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to use this code to hide woocommerce-message but it doesn't work.

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000); // <-- time in mseconds
```

Do you any another solutions ? I tried to put this code into header.php and my template has space for Custom Header JavaScript Code but nothing works.

Comment: if the element is not there at the start, and appears randomly I assume you are going to have to check for when this message appears and then call the set timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast') 
    }, 5000);
```

If you're using wordpress, try

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast') 
    }, 5000);
```

This link may help you as well: [jQuery | on click fade out and / or automatically fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115613/jquery-on-click-fade-out-and-or-automatically-fade-ou)

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. This one for wordpress works great.

Answer (score 3):

if the element pops up and is inserted into the dom randomly you can use an approach like this to remove it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
   $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('.woocommerce-message')) {
           
           setTimeout(function() {
             $('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast');
            alert("node fading"); 
           }, 5000);
        }
    });

   //object inserted after 2 seconds
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('<div class="woocommerce-message">Test node inserted </div>').appendTo('body');
        alert("node inserted");
     },2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It show the error when we use `$(e.target)`.
so ignoring the I have add tweak.

```
jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.woocommerce-error,.woocommerce-message', function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('.woocommerce-error,.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 6000);   
    });
```

Good luck.