# Trying to understand a JS error when hiding WooCommerce messages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to fadeout messages from WooCommerce and use this code which I got from this answer - [Hide woocommerce-message in couple seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924706/hide-woocommerce-message-in-couple-seconds)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('.page-id-18 .woocommerce-message')) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('3000');
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
});
```

I have other jQuery in the (document).ready function but have stripped it out for clarity. It works as expected but I get a lot for error messages in the console that point to the line:

```
if ($(e.target).is('.woocommerce-message')) {
```

The error is: TypeError: s.test is not a function. (In 's.test(t)', 's.test' is undefined) and is repeated. The odd thing is that it appears to work but generates all these errors.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of this error by adding just tweak, It's works for me.

```
jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.woocommerce-error,.woocommerce-message', function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('.woocommerce-error,.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 6000);   
});
```